# Image not loading in the template

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I have an image as attached below,
    [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4z9i.png)

But the code below not loading the image,can nayone please help me.Thanks.

```
<img class="marginright0" img-cache="" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eldorado-medicine/40/microscope_2-512.png" alt="Telemedicine Website" style="width: 48px; height:48px"/>
```

I have given the right path name and the the image name but still I am getting 404 error in the network.

Comment: Check Your Console What its Display ?

Comment: check your console for errors may b the firewall could blocking that url

Comment: I attached an image ...can u pls load that image

Comment: Hi all,Actually I need to edit the code,I am not loading the image form the url there instead from the image I attached.

Comment: @Traveller .. Its Your Image :  `https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4z9i.png`

Comment: If i load it from stack overflow,i.e https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4z9i.png.Its cmg but from my own folder ist not wrkng.

Comment: can you update your Question With Your Code So We get an idea of it !!

Answer (score 0):

**Its Works Fine !!**

```html
<img class="marginright0" img-cache="" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eldorado-medicine/40/microscope_2-512.png" alt="Telemedicine Website" style="width: 48px; height:48px"/>
```

---

**As You Give The Image, Its Png Formated With crop So its only display in black or dark color like this:**

```html
<body style="background: black;">

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4z9i.png" />
</body>
```

Comment: Hi ,I attached an image ...can u pls load that image

Comment: bro its png image with white crop !! wait upload it